# How do I intercept rqt plugin mouse events?

Tags: python, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a virtual joystick plugin for rqt in Python.  When I wrote the stand-alone python node, I just made my main window inherit QtGui.QMainWindow, then I could simply override mousePressEvent.

When I make an rqt plugin, the mousePressEvent doesn't work, I assume because there's nothing to override in the Plugin class.

Is there another way to do this?  Can I connect some QT signal?

Thanks,
-Jon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52841/how-do-i-intercept-rqt-plugin-mouse-events?/) by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 837 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes there is a standard way.

Taking [rqt python plugin tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin) as an example, you can replace `QWidget` with your main `python` modoule, give it to [qt_gui.PluginContext.add_widget](http://ros.org/doc/api/qt_gui/html/classqt__gui_1_1plugin__context_1_1PluginContext.html#a2814e487d31fad6ae983a1e640fd0f5c) method.

---

A little more about concept, `rqt` framework provides:

1. An "interface" between your own python components and `rqt` itself.
2. Standard procedures for GUI (shutdown etc.)
3. Nice features for GUI design (ex. `loadUi` that enables to use UI definition in xml (.ui file)

This means you can easily utilize your own stuff without even modifying. You just add a class that extends `qt_gui.plugin.Plugin` where you define #1 & #2 above. Currently detailed API document doesn't exist but [API Review](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Reviews/2012-06-20_API_Review) might give you more insight.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-01-20**:
Excellent!  That was exactly the tip I needed!